# How can I install python and php editor on Eclipse IDE?

Tags: php, python, eclipse, ide

I tried to install python and php on eclipse ide, (on Mac OSX) but I get a collission.

Has anybody managed to successfully install both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try installing [Aptana Plugin](http://aptana.com/), it should have both of them ...